# Как назначить определенную дату в деле Битрикс24

Tags: битрикс, логика, битрикс24

помогите пожалуйста с выполнением задачи. Я в бизнес-процессе сделал "запланировать звонок" но мне надо что данное действие начиналось в определенное время следующего дня. Я посмотрел документацию, но не нашел примеров, из-за этого проблема возникла. Пример того что я хочу сделать - до лида не дозвонились -> на следующий день в 9:00 будет добавлено дело, для того чтобы снова с ним связаться. П.С. Всё действие выполняется в бизнес-процессе

Comment: Я нашел информацию про функции, и у меня получилось назначить звонок на следующий день после коммуникации, теперь осталось чтобы указывалось точное время коммуникации -> звонок запланирован - завтра в 9:00. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам понадобится завести пару переменных, чтобы сформировать дату со временем.

Схема следующая:

**Переменная_1:** {{=dateadd({=System:Date},"5d")}} (или workdateadd);

**Переменная_2:** Переменная_1 09:00:00 (время через пробел)

В формирование дела подставьте **Переменная_2**.

- Возможно будет достаточно и одной переменной, чтобы сделать сразу так: {{=dateadd({=System:Date},"5d")}} 9:00:00.
  Только тогда эта переменная обязательно должна быть строковая.
  Я обычно пользуюсь двумя вспомогательными переменными.

Comment: Спасибо большое